# Minimal polynomial of a matrix product

Tags: linear-algebra

> Find the minimal polynomial of the matrix $ (a_{ij}) $ when the matrix elements $  a_{ij} $ have the form $ a_{ij} = u_i v_j $.

---

In the matrix form $ A = U^tV $, where the columns of $ U $ and $ V $ are vectors $ u_i $ and $ v_j $. The minimal polynomial is *not* just $ \det(U^tV - \lambda I)  $, what can be proved by considering $ U $ or $ V $ being zero. Can anybody help please?

Comment: Compute $A^2$. How is that related to $A$?

Comment: In terms of what?

Comment: Just compute $A^2$. Can you find a simple expression for that?

Comment: Oh sorry, I just I found out that I misunderstood the formulation myself. I considered $ u_i $ and $ v_j $ to be vectors, not scalars.. $ A^2 = (uv)A $ then

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The matrix has rank at most $1$, so the eigenvalue of $0$ has multiplicity at least $n-1$.  Find the other eigenvalue.

Comment: Why is rank of $ A $ at most $ 1 $? $ U $ and $ V $ are completely independent and, for example, if they are both non-singular then $ A $ is non-singular as well

Comment: @Peregrino because $Ax$ is a multiple of $U$ for all $x$

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood the formulation myself.. The other is $ (uv) $

Comment: And therefore the minimal polynomial is $ A(A - uv) $. Thanks.

Comment: @Peregrino Unless $u = 0$ or $v = 0$, when $A = 0$ and the minimal polynomial of $A$ is $X$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: If you are having trouble finding the one potentially non-zero eigenvalue of the matrix, note that for two $m \times n$ matrices $A,B$, the trace satisfies $\hbox{trace}(AB) = \hbox{trace}(BA)$.